# Quand dire « Bonjour » et quand dire « Bonsoir » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, salutations

Par exemple, lorsque l'on rencontre des voisins dans un immeuble ou une résidence, par politesse on les salue en disant « Bonjour » ou « Bonsoir » en fonction de l'heure de la journée.

Cependant, je remarque que bien souvent, on ne sait pas s'il faut employer l'un ou l'autre en fonction de l'heure qu'il est. Par exemple, à 17h30, que doit-on dire ?

Existe-t-il une règle ? Une heure à partir de laquelle on doit dire « Bonsoir » ?

Comment: Suite à diverses questions (celle-ci notamment), il me semble urgent que nous mettions au point (une sorte de typologie, d'organigramme ou de cartographie) disons un schéma détaillant toutes ces conventions informelles. En fonction du degré de proximité avec l'interlocuteur, l'heure de la journée, la perspective de passer les moments à venir en compagnie de l'interlocuteur (ou pas), la région peut-être aussi, voire l'humeur (?) etc.

Comment: Moi je suis américain. Souvent en anglais, on mélange des mots pour avoir un nouveau signification. Donc je commençais dire *bonjoir* vers 17h30, 18h. Effectivement je ne le dis jamais aux magasins, à la banque; je l'utilise plutôt pour les amis et les autres que je connais mieux :) Juuuste une idée ;)

Comment: Notre poète national Jean-Marie Bigard a rendu célèbre le bonjoir http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonjoir

Comment: Un petit "bonjoir" prononcé rapidement évite tout malentendu.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Bonsoir* ne peut être dit que le soir (mais le *soir* n'est pas clairement défini).

Personnellement je n'attends pas qu'il fasse nuit pour dire *bonsoir*, je dirais plutôt que je le dis occasionnellement à partir des alentours de 18h (heure du diner), quand beaucoup de gens ont fini de travailler, c'est donc la fin de journée.

Une fois la nuit tombée, il devient plus rare d'entendre *Bonjour* ceci dit.

*Bonjour* est plutôt commun, passe-partout et pratiquement jamais choquant.

Par contre, si vous n'êtes pas le premier à saluer, il est souvent coutume de répondre la même chose que votre interlocuteur, par ordre pratique et parfois pour éviter de gêner.

Certains préciseront volontairement *Bonsoir* dans l'intention de corriger et l'interlocuteur peut par exemple alors répondre « Ah oui c'est vrai [pardon][, bonsoir !] ».

En parlant de gêne, il peut arriver que les deux personnes se souhaitent *Bonjour* et *Bonsoir* en même temps, résultant alors parfois en la personne étant légèrement gênée (si elle ne réagit pas comme le cas ci-dessus) la poussant parfois à vouloir se corriger.

Personnellement, à mon travail, j'utilise presque toujours *Bonjour* au client (surtout car je ne sais pas forcément quelle heure il est, s'il est déjà tard ou non) le plus important pour moi étant surtout la forme de politesse pour dire au revoir. Au lieu d'un simple au revoir je préfère tenter d'être plus approprié en précisant correctement *Au revoir et bonne (fin de) journée* ou *après midi*, *soir*, et/ou *Bon week-end* ou *Bonnes fêtes*, etc. étant toujours plus chaleureux.

Comment: Merci de cette bonne réponse même si elle est un peu évasive sur la fin :-).

Comment: "heure du diner" ?! Je sais pas où tu vis mais personne ne dinne à cette heure ci dans mon coin.

Comment: @Knu Ce que je sais c'est que les Belges disent respectivement déjeuner, diner et souper pour les 3 repas majeurs de la journée là où les Français disent petit-déjeuner, déjeuner et diner.

Comment: Ce que je veux dire c'est que les français dinnent en général vers 19h30–20h (heure du journal).

Comment: @Knu > déjà que l'absence de règle concernant le "bonsoir" rend la discution récurrente, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait besoin d'introduire un nouveau débat sur l'heure du dîner, surtout avec des généralités venues de je-ne-sais-où...

Answer (score 14):

Personnellement, j'ai tendance à dire *Bonjour* tant que la nuit n'est pas tombée.

Par conséquent, à 17h30, je dirai *Bonjour* en été et *Bonsoir* en hiver.

Comment: Tu préconises donc _Bonjour_ lorsque le soleil n'est pas encore couché même à 20h30 ?

Comment: @Zistoloen: Oui, pourquoi pas ?

Comment: Personnellement, je dis _Bonsoir_ à 20h30 peu importe la saison ; dire _Bonjour_ à 20h30 en juin me parait bizarre. Sinon, ce n'est pas moi qui ait appliqué un vote négatif à ta réponse.

Answer (score 11):

Si les gens hésitent, c'est qu'il n'y a en pratique pas de règles ; si *bonsoir* ne s'utilise que tard dans la journée, *bonjour* se dit sans réel problème à peu près n'importe quand.

De plus, je suis loin d'être sûr que l'heure soit le seul facteur. Je vais plus facilement dire *bonsoir* si j'ai l'intention de passer la soirée avec la personne que je salue qu'en entrant dans un magasin par exemple.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Les gens peuvent hésiter car ils ne connaissent pas la règle, non ?

Comment: Une règle aussi peu connue n'a guère de valeur que pour celui qui l'emploie.

Comment: +1 pour relativiser l'heure par rapport à la période à laquelle on se réfère.

Comment: Dans le même ordre d'idée, je pense dire "Bonjour" si j'estime que ma journée ou celle de mon interlocuteur est en cours, et dire "Bonsoir" si j'estime que ma journée ou celle de mon interlocuteur se termine. Ça dépend donc moins de l'heure elle-même que du contexte.

Comment: @biozic: finalement, je suis assez d'accord avec ça.

Comment: Une des différence simple qui va dans ce sens, c'est qu'il est commun de se quitter sur un *bonsoir* en fin de journée, mais *bonjour* n'est pas une forme communément utilisée en se séparant quelque soit l'heure.

Answer (score 6):

C'est l'un des plus grands problèmes pour les étrangers en France !

Pour moi, quand j'y vivais, je disais *Bonjour* le matin et quand j'étais au travail mais une fois parti, je disais *Bonsoir*.

Comment: On le dit aussi aux collègues avant de partir.

Answer (score 6):

Dans mon pays la Côte d'Ivoire on dit *Bonsoir* à partir de 14h, cette formule me gêne beaucoup. À vrai dire je pense toujours qu'il préférable de dire *Bonsoir* à partir de 18h30 en hiver comme en été, ce qui correspond en général à la fin de la journée de travail.

Answer (score 4):

En France métropolitaine, « *Bonjour* » s'utilise le matin et l'après-midi.

On emploie « *Bonsoir* » à partir de la fin de l'après-midi, au coucher du soleil et toute la soirée.

« *Bonne nuit* » est plutôt réservé au moment du coucher.

Toutefois, dans l'usage, il est fréquent d'utiliser le « *bonjour* » à l’adresse d’une personne que l'on voit pour la première fois à n'importe quelle heure, même le soir (dans le cadre d'une présentation par exemple lors d'une soirée).

---

« *Bonjour* » est la forme masculine de « *Bonne journée* ».

La forme masculine est employée pour ouvrir le dialogue et la forme féminine sert à le conclure.

---

source: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour

Answer (score 3):

Plus sérieusement, comme en toute sorte d’usages en langue française, la chose dépends du pays. En Afrique subsaharienne francophone, on dit bonsoir dès 14h00 passée — même s’il fait plein jour et que le soleil quitte à peine le zénith — ce qui peut dérouter un européen.

En revanche (quoique je ne me souvienne plus où, au Québec peut-être) *bonsoir* se dit très exactement à partir de 8h du soir.
Au Maghreb encore, j’ai constaté qu’on ne dit *bonsoir* que lorsque le temps commence à devenir gris.

Comment: Ce n'est vraiment pas au Québec que *bonsoir* se dit seulement à partir de 20h.

Answer (score 1):

Un jour compte 24h on peut donc dire bonjour à n'importe quel moment du  jour. Mais bonsoir le matin serait un peu bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire **bonjour** à 17h30 si l'on ne s'est pas vu depuis le matin ici en RDC.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse ! On manque d'expertise des français Africains sur ce site, donc un contributeur de RDC est particulièrement bienvenu. Est-ce que 17h30 (donc le début du coucher du soleil) est l'heure limite ? Est-ce que tout le monde suit à peu près la même limite ?

Answer (score 1):

En règle générale :

Bonjour le matin, midi et après midi et lorsqu'on voit une personne pour la première fois et qu'on va passer du temps avec elle.

Bonsoir dès que la journée de **travail** est terminée.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis au Honduras et j'ai un collègue qui vient d'Haïti. Tous les jours je suis  choquée quand j'arrive au boulot à 15h et tout le monde me dit: bonsoir! 
J'ai expliqué qu'en France on dit bonsoir aux alentours de 18h mais ils continuent de dire bonsoir :( alors que je dis bonjour !

Answer (score 1):

Ici chez moi au Togo, on nous apprend depuis le cours primaire à dire bonsoir après 12h (midi). Pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas une règle bien définie ?

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que le début de coucher de soleil est la limite d'utilisation entre bonjour et bonsoir.

Et rien avoir entre si on est à l'intérieur ou l'extérieur.

Answer (score 0):

Ce que on peux constater c'est que, même parmi les locuteurs natifs, il n'y a pas de consensus. Certains avouent que, parfois eux-mêmes, ils hésitent. Selon Le Figaro :

> Il est 17h. Vous croisez une de vos connaissances dans la rue. Le seul mot que vous lui adressez est «bonjour». Elle rétorque, comme si elle avait besoin de vous corriger, «bonsoir». Malaise. C'est la seule parole que vous lui avez adressée et vous n'avez même pas été capable de trouver le mot juste. Et imaginez que, si la locution nous pose un problème, elle est d'autant plus délicate à employer pour les étrangers. Il suffit de taper «bonjour or bonsoir» sur internet pour voir la quantité de forums qui tentent d'apporter une réponse au problème.

(...)

> Remonter à l’origine de l’expression nous permettra sans doute de mieux comprendre son usage. « Bonsoir » est utilisé dès le XVe siècle, sous l’écriture de « boinsoir », nous indique le Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales. Le terme vient du latin « bonus », qui veut dire « bon », et de « serus », c’est-à-dire « tardivement ». Par « bonsoir », le locuteur veut souhaiter une bonne soirée, un « bon » soir, à la personne à laquelle il s’adresse. Mais alors quand commence la soirée ?
>
> S’il faut se fixer une norme, regardons du côté des guides de savoir-vivre. Mais, de même que chacun a sa notion de « se lever tôt », « dîner tôt », le mot « tard » est une notion relative. Selon les précis que l’on peut consulter, la soirée commence à l’heure de la fin du travail et des activités quotidiennes, donc plutôt vers 17h30-18h. Ou bien quand le soleil se couche et que la nuit arrive, ce qui varie en fonction des saisons.
>
> En conjuguant les différentes observations sur l’usage de « bonsoir », on peut retenir qu’à partir du moment où le jour décline, il est possible d’employer le mot. En règle générale, c’est entre 17h30 et 18h que « bonsoir » se substitue à « bonjour ». Il est également d’usage d’employer « bonsoir » pour ouvrir la discussion et son équivalent féminin « bonne soirée » pour la clore. Mais un « bonjour », même à la tombée de la nuit, ne sera jamais mal pris.

Extraits tirés d'un article dans Le Figaro disponible ici :

https://www.france-pittoresque.com/spip.php?article14790

et ici :

https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2018/02/16/37002-20180216ARTFIG00018-bonjour-ou-bonsoir-que-faut-il-choisir.php

Answer (score -1):

Le matin, au lever du soleil, l'après-midi et jusqu'au coucher du soleil on dit bonjour et à partir de 19h on dit bonsoir. Par contre, en hiver où il y a peu de soleil, on commence à dire bonsoir à partir de 18h :)

Answer (score -2):

Je pense qu'on peut dire  bonjour, tant qu'il y a le jour et la même chose pour bonsoir.

Comment: C'est la règle en général

Comment: Pas vraiment. On ne dit jamais bonsoir le matin alors qu'il fait encore nuit.

Comment: @jlliagre: je ne pense pas que ce soit ce que Mehdi voulait dire,. Il voulait sûrement spécifier qu'on peut dire _bonjour_ lorsqu'il fait jour et _bonsoir_ lorsqu'il fait nuit.

Comment: @Zistoloen On peut aussi dire bonjour quand il fait nuit et bonsoir quand il fait jour.

Comment: @jlliagre: je suis d'accord mais ce n'est pas forcément l'opinion de tout le monde. Et comme il n'existe pas de règles spécifiques à ce sujet...

Comment: @Zistoloen Il ne s'agit pas d'une opinion mais d'une constatation. Personne ne dit bonsoir en arrivant au boulot à 5 heures du matin.

Comment: @jlliagre: je suis d'accord. Mehdi pensait sûrement qu'à partir du moment où il fait nuit le soir on peut dire bonsoir. Il n'a juste pas pensé à toutes les éventualités.

Comment: Oui mais c'est bien le problème et c'est ce qui fait qu'il existe une question sur StackExchange. Il fait jour jusqu'à 22h en été et il fait nuit jusqu'à 9h en hiver. Donc on en revient au problème de l'heure, et non du Soleil.

Answer (score -2):

Selon les guides de savoir vivre on commence à dire bonsoir à partir de 17h30.

Comment: Bonjour! A-t-on un exemple d'un tel guide qu'on pourrait lier ici (intégrer le lien en mettant un élément en surbrillance dans l'éditeur puis cliquer sur le bouton lien, coller le lien +ok) ? Merci et bonne recherche !

Answer (score -4):

Bonjour pour le jour *Day*
Bonsoir pour le soir *Night*
Bonne après-midi *Afternoon*