# Formal saying of “Welcome”, as a salutation, in French

Tags: salutations

I need to know how to say you're welcome, but to my French teacher. I need to know what to use, I have found this phrase so far:

> Vous êtes les bienvenus.

Comment: Since the tag was *salutation*, I assumed you really meant it as a salutation and not as an answer to “thank you”.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for the French equivalent of *You're welcome* being the answer to *Thank you*, it is **De rien** or **Je vous en prie** or **Il n'y a pas de quoi**.

If you're looking for the French equivalent of *You're welcome* being a salutation (as *Welcome* or *Be welcome*) then it is **Soyez les bienvenus** or **Bienvenue**.

Comment: Malgré le fait que votre réponse soit exacte, je crois que dépendamment du contexte, un simple Bonjour est acceptable. En tant que Francophone vivant dans une ville Francophone, rares sont les occasions ou ont nous dira "Soyez les bienvenus", dans un commerce ou un restaurant par exemple.

Comment: nota: in some french-speaking countries, *bienvenu* also means *you're welcome* as an answer to *thank you*.

Answer (score 2):

When inviting your teacher to your place, you can start the conversation with

> Bonjour. Soyez le/la bienvenu(e).

or

> Bonjour et bienvenue.

or

> Bonjour, je vous souhaite la bienvenue.

All fit perfectly the situation. You can also choose to add the name of your teacher after “*bonjour*”, [or](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/quand-dire-bonjour-et-quand-dire-bonsoir) “*bonsoir*”.

Comment: When I answer something, the teachers says "Merci", and I like to tell him You're Welcome! in return.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: Then this is a completely different question. You tagged the question “salutation”, so it seemed you were asking about greetings. Well, now, it's best to leave this question as is. You may ask a new question (and please make clear what you're looking for this time). You may also have a look at [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/informal-ways-of-saying-youre-welcome-in-french), since [*je vous en prie*](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2936/79) is actually the most formal answer to “merci”.